# Get children from parent Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

If I have:

```
var Game = Sequelize.define('game');
var Move = Sequelize.define('move');
Move.belongsTo(Game);
```

How do I get a set of games with all moves? It seems I can easily get all moves with games:

```
Move.findAll({include: Game});
```

But not the other way around?

```
Game.findAll({include: Move});
```

Gives me `Unhandled rejection Error: Move (move) is not associated to game!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the association both ways

```
Game.hasMany(Move);
```

Comment: Do you mean I need to add this AS WELL as the above code? Doesn't that affect the schema? ... Oh, it won't, will it? As it already has the information - I assume that line will be required to make it clear to Sequelize. I wonder if something could be mentioned in the getting started docs about that? Anyway. Thanks!!